# Reading a value from a database

Tags: android, database, select, if-statement, return

I have a database in my app with several columns of which 3 are: `_id` `name` `selected`.
Now, I want to read a single `selected` value from a row with the `name` being a string I get from some code. What would be the best way to do this?
Thanks

P.S. I am getting that value to check if it's 0 or 1 (only two possible values), so I want to ask how to make a kind of an `if` statement in the `return` field? I have seen some people do it with something resembling this: `return true ? ... false`

**EDIT:**
Okay, this is my code atm, haven't checked it yet since I need to do some other things to get it all up, but I think there may be a better way to do this.

```
public boolean isBandSelected(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor cursor = mDb.query("bands", new String[] { "selected" }, "name="
            + name, null, null, null, null);
    int index = cursor.getColumnIndex("selected");
    String selected = cursor.getString(index);
    return selected == "1";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  What column is this 0 or 1 under?  And by the way, that syntax is `return a_condition ? this_if_true : this_if_false`

Comment: Please provide a complete code snippet that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: p.s. It sounds like you are describing the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Comment: @Code-Guru I don't know what part of the code to post that would be beneficial to my question. As I stated I just want to get a value from one column of the database that is in a row which contains the given value of another column. English is not my native language, but I try to explain my problem as best as I can! :)

Comment: What type is the "selected" column in the underlying database?

Comment: Should have been an `int` but from a different problem it's now a string..

Comment: In this situation, I think it would be easier to use an int, especially if the column in the database is declared as an Integer. This will help you avoid the mistake of using == to compare Strings.

Comment: well for now i will use `return "1".equals(selected); ` as wawlian suggested, will change after if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression to match rows whose name field being string. Many databases can support regular expression.

The ternary operator(? :) can be used to make return statement like this.

```
return value == 0 ? false : true
```

But it depends on what kind of data type you what to return. Code above returns boolean data type.

The last line of your code above will always return `false`. This is because the `==` operator compares the reference of the two objects. you can use:

```
return "1".equals(selected);
```

Comment: You don't need a ternary operator for that.  Just return `value != 0`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just guess the questioner was ask about ternary operator.

Comment: Thanks for the replies mates but can anyone elaborate a bit further on the "values from databases" matter? :)

Comment: @AleksaPavlovic Do you mean you want some examples of how to query data from database in detail?

Comment: Well, I posted the code how I read a single value now in the edit, but I am wondering if this is the right way of things, is there a more efficient way, since this is just a "scaled down" version of my code which I use to select all data with some limitations.